# Get the percentage of loaded resources in a WebView

Tags: objective-c, webkit, webview

So I want to have like a percentage of how much the website is loaded.  I'm not really sure how to do it except I'm guessing it's sort of related to the WebFrameLoadDelegate.  I can use all of the delegates to create an approximate percentage of the page being loaded, but I'd rather have a much more accurate way of calculating the load percentage.  So any help or ideas would be nice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can use WebView's estimatedProgress to get it's number of resources loaded.